# Get quote tweets and correct retweets with rtweet library

Tags: r, twitter, rtweet

```
tweet_status_id <- "1594049106615291907"
tweet_retweeter_ids <- rtweet::get_retweeters(status_id = tweet_status_id)
tweet_retweets <- rtweet::get_retweets(status_id = tweet_status_id, n = 1000)

dim(tweet_retweets)
table(tweet_retweets$is_quote)
```

Using rtweet to analyze our tweets, having an issue with counting retweets and with identifying quote tweets. Here is the tweet - https://twitter.com/BillGates/status/1594049106615291907 - for the code above.

As of this posting, the tweet has 536 retweets and 267 quote tweets. However, in `tweet_retweets`, there are only 94 retweets and all 94 of them are `isQuote == FALSE`. How do we get the correct number of retweets and quote tweets for a tweet using its statusId?

Comment: It looks like there is a limit of the latest 100 retweets, which explains why we do not get all retweets. On a smaller tweet (10 retweets and 5 quote tweets), we are still only receiving the 10 retweets, not the 5 quote tweets.